# Is it possible to reliably execute a callback on an ActiveRecord jsonb column assignment or change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to execute some additional functionality in an ActiveRecord model when a jsonb column value is assigned to or when it changes.

My model is simple, it just contains a single jsonb column called payload. My current thinking is to override the column setter, but this doesn't seem to work as expected:

```rb
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def payload=(jsonb)
    pp 'Setter called...'
    super(jsonb)
  end
end
```

With the above model the following works:

```rb
ent = Entity.new
ent.payload = {}
#>> Setter called...
ent.save!
```

but subsequently the following syntax does not:

```rb
ent.payload["attribute"] = "value"
#>> ...
```

Is there any way to trigger code or fire a callback that works for both methods of assignment (inline and explict)?

I am aware that it is possible to hook into the ActiveModel dirty attributes to check if the jsonb value has changed at other points such as before_save, but these are reliant on active model callbacks.

I am specifically looking for a way to react to the change when it occurs, on assignment, not on subsequent events in the model life-cycle.

Comment: Framework challenge: Do you really think a JSONB column is a good idea here? This is basically two anti-patterns stacked on top of each other - using JSON instead of relational modeling and callbacks. This screams that you should have a separate model and/or services taking care of it.

Comment: While this is a bit outside of the scope of the question, yes, I know what I am doing with the json column.

If you want a bit of background, I am investigating as part of a POC to see if we can replace an existing complex Entity-Attribute-Value database schema with some jsonb columns to improve useability and speed. 

[Here is some reading if you are interested.](https://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/)

Comment: That definately changes the premise of the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign attribute / value, you call other method under the hood -- `Hash#[]=`

So if you decide to change its behavior you need to override like this

```
class Hash
  def []=(key, val)
    pp 'Setter called...'
    super(key, val)
  end
end
```

But keep in mind that such monkeypatch will affect not only this model, but everywhere when you will assign hash key

According to the comment you can define your own class

```
class TalkingHash < Hash
  def []=(key, val)
    pp 'Setter called...'
    super(key, val)
  end
end

ent = Entity.new

ent.payload = TalkingHash.new
# Setter called...

ent.payload[:nested] = TalkingHash.new
# Setter called...

ent.payload[:nested][:attribute] = :value
# Setter called...
```

Comment: Ok, I can see the direction you are going with this. Id have a couple of follow up questions on it to see if its possible to adapt to the above usecase:  

1. Does this work for deeply nested properties, or just top level key assignment?  

2. Is there a feasible way to create a subclass (EventHash or some-such) and force this specific implentation instead of the default Hash object for this specific column representation?

Comment: 1. No - nested hashes are just separate instances of hash. 2. [Subclassing Hash is a *really bad idea*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzdSxgVPhXU) (or any of the Ruby core classes) - they are implemented in C and do not behave as you would expect. While you could potentially use the attributes API to make your column serialize into your augmented hash class it won't solve anything as that class doesn't actually know about the model.

Comment: @max it seems to me that the initial idea of setter logging is a bad one :)

Comment: @mechnicov yeah, I'm not complete sure how to solve it but I think this smells like shoehorning way to much into a single model.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that the original goal is bad. It would be a pretty common pattern to override getters and setters to transform data or enable other functionality on a normal string or int column in ActiveRecord, so why not jsonb? 

On subclassing Hash, I agree that this is not a clean approach to the problem. I'll keep looking for other solutions...

Comment: The goal isn't bad - you just need a very different solution like updating the record through a service object instead of using callbacks or creating a model that just wraps the dynamic data and creating setters/getters via metaprogramming.